# Assets not uploading to S3

Tags: assets

I recently switched host to DigitalOcean and also moved my assets onto S3. The system is freezing when I upload an asset which seems to be 1mb or over, I have altered my php.ini file to make sure this wasn't the culprit.

There is also an issue with some images appearing and others not. I'm getting this message when looking at some files

> This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The >document tree is shown below.

When I add a policy statement this seems to disappear but I'm not sure if this was even required, hard to see how other files are showing up.

In craft_assetsources I have the following which still seems to carry the old url??

```
{"path":"images\/ads\/","url":"http:\/\/digbmx.com\/images\/ads\/","keyId":"AKIAJCJA6QHXEOAZ2LMA","secret":"EDGceqipqQOSqM7ItU8L52oT+ZjQD+pnK\/Z+30gW","bucket":"digbmx","subfolder":"ads\/","urlPrefix":"http:\/\/s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com\/digbmx\/","expires":"","location":"eu-west-1"}
```

Any help on these issues would be much appreciated.

Thanks, Dc

Comment: UPDATE: I have got the permissions fixed on the files. It seems that when I upload them to S3 directly they do not have READ access set, I was able to batch change them all using 'Bucket Explorer'.

Comment: THE MAIN PROBLEM now is that I cannot upload a file over a MB, smaller files are okay, they upload and appear in the assets panel but large files just stall?? any help would be appreciated.